# What does it mean: "the ContentControl does not use the DataTemplate automatically."?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, contentcontrol

I am struggling to get my datatemplate binding to work; I explicitly bind my DataTemplate to a datatype

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ExcelReportVM}">
    <local:ExcelReport DoubleClickHandler="{Binding}">
        <local:ExcelReport.RowColorConverter>
            <local:ReportRowColorConverter/>
        </local:ExcelReport.RowColorConverter>
    </local:ExcelReport>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, I found that even though my `control.DataContext` is `ExcelReportVM`, the above `DataTemplate` is simply not applied.

Then I [read in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx) that

> if you are binding a ContentControl to a collection of Task objects, 
>   the ContentControl does not use the DataTemplate automatically. This
>   is because the binding on a ContentControl needs more information to
>   distinguish whether you want to bind to an entire collection or the
>   individual objects. If your ContentControl is tracking the selection
>   of an ItemsControl type, you can set the Path property of the
>   ContentControl binding to "/" to indicate that you are interested in
>   the current item. For an example, see How to: Bind to a Collection and
>   Display Information Based on Selection. Otherwise, you need to specify
>   the DataTemplate explicitly by setting the ContentTemplate property.

The explanation sounds very abstract and I have no idea what it is talking about after reading it a few times. Anyone care to explain it with a proper example?

Comment: What kind of control is "control"?

Comment: @mm8 , as defined in the data template datatype , ExcelReportVM, no?

Comment: You set the DataContext property of some "control". What is this?

Comment: @Graviton, if there is a DataTemplate for ExcelReportVM and a view shows ExcelReport control for ExcelReportVM object that means template *was* applied. Otherwise ExcelReportVM would be displayed as TextBlock with "ExcelReportVM" text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicit `DataTemplate` is applied if you set or bind the `Content` property of a `ContentControl` to an instance of an `ExcelReportVM` object:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="control" />
```

---

```
content.Content = new ExcelReportVM();
```